# FragmentTransaction.replace between two fragments shows the activity

Tags: android, replace

I have an activity and it shows two full-screen fragments (fragmentOne and fragmentTwo)

When I switch from fragmentOne to fragmentTwo the activity shows for one or two seconds.

I need the activity does not shows.

I have this code:

```
public void stackAnimatedFragment(int containerViewId, BaseFragment fragment, int enter, int exit, int popEnter, int popExit) {
    String tag = fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(enter, exit, popEnter, popExit);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(containerViewId, fragment, tag);
  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());  
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

A visual Example:

Activity - green background
FragmentOne - black background
FragmentTwo - white background

Expected result: showing black background, do replace, see white background.
Actual result: showing black background, do replace, see green background for a second, see white background.

Comment: could it be caused by your animations?

Comment: what do you actually mean by 'Activity shows'

Comment: Description edited

Comment: post code of your animations that you are passing to `setCustomAnimations()`

Comment: I pass all parameters as 0